# Is there anything similar to Java AutoValue in C#?

Tags: java, c#, auto-value

After working on a Java project for some time then coming back to C#, I've found myself really missing AutoValue. Specifically, I'd like the ability to:

- Produce an immutable value class with minimal boilerplate.
- Have things like equality and hash code automatically handled for me.
- Ideally, have it automatically generate a builder to allow fluent construction and arbitrary validation like "if you give parameter A, you must also give B".
- In the same vein, a toBuilder()-style function to make a deep copy of an existing instance while making some modifications.

All of that would have been really easy with AutoValue. Is there anything similar? I could, of course, implement all that functionality myself, but it's a lot of boilerplate, making it harder to maintain and more error-prone.

Comment: Perhaps T4 templates will do the job?

Comment: It seems like the concept of records discussed in that blog post are actually exactly what I want. How timely! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described, it seems that you will need to wait until [C#9 record types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#records) in order to get what you've described of java's `AutoValues`, i.e. in C#9, you should be able to declare:

```
public data class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

You'll then get:

- Immutable behaviour
- The benefit of [C#'s object initialiser syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)
- An automatic default implementation of [equality and hashcode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#value-based-equality)
- [With expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#with-expressions) will allow the `copy most properties, but allowing some field values to be changed during the copy.

In the interim (C#8 and prior), you'll need to do some of this by hand, i.e.

- Declare your class properties as [get only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939225)
- Initialise all properties via a constructor
- Create your own static factory / builder methods
- Use [code generation tools in IDE's like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019) to generate equality members

As an aside, if you have just switched from Java to C#, you may not be aware of `structs` as value types for trivial 'records', which [from the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/)

> Structs are best suited for very small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created.

Although structs do have a default implementation of value equality, this can be unacceptable given that it is just the first field included in the [hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927853), and that you'd need to provide an implementation of [operator ==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15199026) if you want to use `==` for value equality.

That said, the use cases for [structs must be carefully considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-should-i-use-a-struct-rather-than-a-class-in-c), and should generally be used only for trivial immutable records or for performance reasons when used in arrays.

Comment: Yes, records seem to be very close to what I'm wanting, leaving out only builders. A shame this project wasn't in a few months.