# List in dropdownbox in grid does not return value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik-grid

I have an enum

```
enum SendDays
{
    Maandag = 1,
    Dinsdag,
    Vandaag= 99
}
```

And a Class

```
public struct DayListModel
{
    public int Id;
    public string DayName;
}
```

I fill a list with days like this

```
private void Filldays()
{
   foreach(int i in Enum.getValues(typeof(SendDays)))
   {
        DayListModel day =new DaylistModel()
        {
            Id = i,
            Dayname = Enum.GetName(typeof(SendDays), i)
         };
         DayList.Add(day);
   }
```

When I use this is in A telerik RadGridView in a radcombobox
like

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Bindning DayList}" DisplayMemberPath="DayName" SelectedValue="{Bindning DefaultSendDay}" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Whenever I change the selecteditem this is not passed.

Any suggestions?

Jeroen

Comment: `SelectedValuePath` must denote the name of a property. Your `Id` is a field. `DayListModel` should also be a class, not a struct.

Comment: What type is `DefaultSendDay`?

Comment: DefaultSendDay is a  Byte (smallint in SQL, Byte through Entity Framework)

Comment: It should be the same type as the `Id`, i.e. `int`.

Comment: @JeroenE: So make `DayListModel.Id` a `byte` as well.

Comment: The difference in types was a key flaw in the original post, Matching those solved most of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my advice, and how I got it to work:

1. Like @mm8 said, you should make the `DayListModel` a class not a struct, and turn the [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) into [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). If you don't use properties, the `DisplayMemberPath` doesn't work. Some stuff doesn't work with structs (like [using `==` to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199026/comparing-two-structs-using)) so I would go with a class in this case.
2. Are your objects observable in your view model? I don't know telerik, but you should be calling some sort of `PropertyChanged` method so the UI can update. If you use a framework like [MVVM light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) it has `ObservableObject`s and `RaisePropertyChanged` methods.

Here is a working example:

`MainWindowVM.cs`

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainWindowVM : ObservableObject
    { 
        private List<DayListModel> _DayList;
        public List<DayListModel> DayList
        {
            get { return _DayList; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _DayList)
                {
                    _DayList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        private DayListModel _DefaultSendDay;
        public DayListModel DefaultSendDay
        {
            get { return _DefaultSendDay; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _DefaultSendDay)
                {
                    _DefaultSendDay = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            DayList = new List<DayListModel>();
            foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SendDays)))
            {
                DayListModel day = new DayListModel()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    DayName = Enum.GetName(typeof(SendDays), i)
                };
                DayList.Add(day);
            }
            DayList = new List<DayListModel>(DayList);
        }
    }

    public enum SendDays
    {
        Maandag = 1,
        Dinsdag,
        Vandaag = 99
    }

    public class DayListModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid >
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DayList}" SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultSendDay}" DisplayMemberPath="DayName" >
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DefaultSendDay.DayName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a combobox and textblock displaying the selectd value]

Comment: Thanks for this example. The main issues where turning the struct into class, fields into properties and matching DefaultSendDay and Id both as Byte. I accepted your answer because it shows it all.

Comment: Thanks, although I didn't make the Id a byte in mine. You may want to [make the enum a byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the types matches, i.e. if your `DefaultSendDay` source property is a `byte`, the `Id` of the `DayListModel` should also be a `byte`.

If it still doesn't work, try to convert the fields into properties and the struct to a class:

```
public class DayListModel
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string DayName { get; set; }
}
```